# Expressjs: Modifying the route path for versioning

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In ExpressJS application,  consider for the given paths

```
GET /v1/users/detail
GET /v2/users/detail
```

the routers are,

```
// v1/users.js
router.get('/v1/users/detail', (req, res, next) => res.send('v1'));

// v2/users.js
router.get('/v2/users/detail', (req, res, next) => res.send('v2'));
```

Since I planned to have header based versioning, I planned to do like this,

```
// users.js
router.get('/users/detail', routesVersioning({
    '1.0.0': (req, res, next) => res.send('v1'),
    '2.0.0': (req, res, next) => res.send('v2'),
}));
```

Basically my clients will use the same URLs(version in the path) but my middleware should rewrite the url with version headers.

**What I tried:**

```
app.use('/v(1|2)/users/*', (req, res, next) => {
  const [_, version] = req.originalUrl.split('/');
  if (version === 'v1') {
    req.version = '1.0.0';
  } else {
    req.version = '2.0.0';
  }
  // req.originalUrl = req.originalUrl.replace(/\/v(1|2)/i, '');
  req.url = req.originalUrl.replace(/\/v(1|2)/i, '');
  next('route'); // tried next(); too
});

app.get('/users/detail', routesVersioning({
        '1.0.0': (req, res, next) => res.send('v1'),
        '2.0.0': (req, res, next) => res.send('v2'),
    }));
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

This won't work since `req.url` is [not being watched by express on every handler](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/dc538f6e810bd462c98ee7e6aae24c64d4b1da93/lib/router/index.js#L136). It will be parsed in the beginning. Actually modifying `req.url` or anything inside the `req` object is not something that you want to do.

What you can do instead is :

```
 app.use( '/v2', v2Router );
 app.use( '/v1', v1Router );

 const v1Router = express.Router(),
       v2Router = express.Router();

 v1Router.get( '/users/details', ( req, res ) => res.send( 'v1' ) );
 v2Router.get( '/users/details', ( req, res ) => res.send( 'v2' ) );
```

Comment: Oh huh, that's really sad for me.

Comment: You can programatically add the versions as well. `['v1','v2'].forEach( v => app.use( v, routers[v] )`. I'm sorry that I have to disappoint you :(